# Inserting Hexadecimal varchar into image column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a project at work to move data from client to another. The only way we could achieve this, due to multiple security policies, is by exporting the data to a csv and the import the csv by the other client.

I then run a merge script to get all the data into their respective columns and tables. Everything works fine except for the image value.

The only way to extract the image value is to convert it down to a varchar(max) and then again to import it as varchar(max). The data however stays in the correct format throughout, but when I import it into the image column it gets converted into the wrong format.

I have tried multiple conversions and casts, but nothing is working. Is there anyway I can maybe avoid the column from doing additional conversions as the variable is already in the correct format?

How the value should be: (just a short part as it is an extremely long string)
FFD8FFE000
How the column converts it:
0x464644384646

It looks like the string gets converted from hexadecimal to decimal.

Comment: Intresting security policies that let you copy (sensitive?) data around using csv but allowing nothing else  ;)

Answer (score 2):

Because you aren't telling SQL server how to convert it. `'FFD8FFE000'` as a `varbinary` *is* `0x46464438464645303030` because you haven't let SQL Server know it's a pre-formatted string. Instead, provide a style code to let SQL Server know it's already formatted as a binary:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(varbinary(max),'FFD8FFE000',2);
```

This returns `0xFFD8FFE000`.

Notice, as well, I use `varbinary(MAX)` too. `image` has been deprecated since *2005* (that's **16 years** ago); it's long past time you stopped using it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately it's the way our DB's are set up so we have to work with it. Your solution works with selecting the value, but it still gets converted wrong with the insert. I did the insert like this: (SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),@profilePicture,2)). If I select the value separately it returns correctly, but for some reason the insert still converts it differently

Comment: Unfortunately you can't have `'FFD8FFE000'` automatically infer to use style code `2`, @Jaco , you need to, in some way, specify to SQL Server the string is pre-formatted. That isn't anything to do with the database, it's the application layer you need to change (presumably that's generating the `INSERT` statement).

Comment: I am not completely sure how they set the insert up on the application layer, I only work on the DB side, but I know they have some conversion taking place. Unfortunately this is not something I can do through our application. I need to move certain individual data from one client to the other client. I wanted to just do a backup and restore, but because of their security policies I am not allowed to take a backup to the other client.

Comment: If you're scripting out the data, why are you converting it to `varchar` at all? Don't. To write a binary value in SQL Server *don't* put the value in single quotes, and prefix it with `0x`. For example `SELECT 0xFFD8FFE000;` will return the `varbinary` value `0xFFD8FFE000` *not* the `varchar` `'0xFFD8FFE000'`.

Comment: I had to convert it to varchar in order to get the csv extract, management studio didn't allow me to do the extract while it was still an image data type. I tried adding the 0x prefix, but it still got converted during the import

Comment: Presumable because you are trying to insert it as a `varchar`, @Jaco . `'0xFFD8FFE000'`, `'FFD8FFE000'` and `0xFFD8FFE000` are all *different* values when treated as their literal data types (`varchar(12)`, `varchar(10)` and `varbinary(5)` respectively).

Comment: It seems you should be asking a new question @Jaco , showing the code you have, and the error you're getting, as it seems what we have here is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).